# Not working properly the condition of the If-Elif Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

The conditional if-elif on Python is not working, please help me.

The way it must be is if you enter the correct username and password (one of the users), then the corresponding message is displayed. If the if condition is not met, then run elif.

```
login = input("Введите логин: ")
passwd = input("Введите пароль: ")

if login == 'gleb' and passwd == 'gleb2806':
    print("Рад видеть Вас администратор Глеб!")

if login == 'kostya' and passwd == 'kostya1':
    print("Рад видеть Вас модератор Костантин!")

elif login != 'gleb' and passwd != 'gleb2806' and login != 'kostya' and passwd != 'kostya1':
    print("Система Вас не распознала. Повторите попытку ещё раз - это бесплатно!")
```

Comment: Why don't you have `if ... elif ... else`?

Comment: Can you specify the error ?

Comment: Also, the `elif` is only for the *second* `if`. The first `if` is totally unrelated.

Comment: your `elif` is also too exclusive. If user enters a valid username with an *incorrect* password, the condition is not captured. Just use `else`.

Comment: If use "elif login != '' and passwd != '' OR login != '' and passwd != '':
    print("Система Вас не распознала. Повторите попытку ещё раз - это бесплатно!")"

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be solution, since you are requiring either of the conditions (if or elif) to be met. Be careful and sure to understand how 'AND' / 'OR' works in if-elif-else conditions.

```
login = input("Введите логин: ")
passwd = input("Введите пароль: ")
if login == 'gleb' and passwd == 'gleb2806':
    print("Рад видеть Вас администратор Глеб!")
elif login == 'kostya' and passwd == 'kostya1':
    print("Рад видеть Вас модератор Костантин!")
else:
    print("Система Вас не распознала. Повторите попытку ещё раз - это бесплатно!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `elif` condition may not capture all combinations for `login` and `passwd`. Use else instead. A combination of correct `login` and wrong `passwd` and vice versa may fail the `elif` condition in your code.

```
login = input("Введите логин: ")
passwd = input("Введите пароль: ")

if login == 'gleb' and passwd == 'gleb2806':
    print("Рад видеть Вас администратор Глеб!")

if login == 'kostya' and passwd == 'kostya1':
    print("Рад видеть Вас модератор Костантин!")

else:
    print("Система Вас не распознала. Повторите попытку ещё раз - это бесплатно!")
```